# No WPF User Control Library Template found in VS 2013

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I am using VS 2013 (Express Version) and I want to create a WPF user Control Library project. But I am not able to find the template in my installed templates list. If I use Winforms, I am able to build a DLL out of my Winforms Application Project just by changing the Output type as "Class Library". But it is not happening in WPF and it is throwing errors if I do so. Is this the correct method of doing it or am I going wrong?

And in the Create New Project dialogue window, I am not able to find the .NET Framework selector drop down. After creating the project only I am able to change the .NET framework version by going inside the properties of the project.

Kindly help me to get out of this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any Updates pending on visual studio?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: I think there are no updates pending.

Comment: For example, in the WPF MainWindow constructor, there will be a function called InitializeComponent(). This function throws error saying, _This function does not belong to this context_. And I was not able to access any of the GUI objects like textbox and buttons. @Default

Comment: That's because a .DLL can't have a main window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been working on this exact same problem for hours this morning. Here is what I think I have learned:

1. With Visual Studio **Express** 2013, it is *by design* that the WPF User Control Library template is not available for making a New Project. This is because it is the free Express version.
2. With the Express version, you don't have a "devenv.exe" for trying the "devenv /installvstemplates" to "fix" things. It is, instead, called (just a moment while I look this up again...) "WDExpress.exe" and will be located (if you have default location) in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE" directory. **BUT** - this won't help you. It won't fix your problem, because, as I mentioned, your Express installation is designed to not have that template available for New Project, so your "fix" won't put it there. I know this because this is what I tried myself. (Also, note that the instructions for doing this tell you to uninstall any extensions you've installed before doing it. And then, of course, if you still want them you have to reinstall them. Like I still have to do, incidentally.) I'm letting you know all of this so you don't go through the headache I'm having.
3. Note that I have not done this yet, so this is somewhat hypothetical on my part, but is based on my research on the Internet so far - Your solution is to create a WPF User Control Library *manually* [but now see UPDATE below]. (No, I don't know how to do this yet. I got into this in the first place, because I'm a WPF novice - just started working with it a few days ago - and late last night I got this great idea to add a "spinner" progress indicator to my "WPF play/learning project" I'm working on, and found a couple of relatively easy-to-work-with samples on the Internet - both of them are a WPF User Control Library - and at first I wanted to use the copy-and-paste to put the code in. But then I discovered... well, our mutual problem, because I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013. No such template under New Project. And literally at the tail end of my about-to-throw-in-the-towel, I'm googling and your post, Dhivakar, is already showing up with the right Google search.) So I haven't finished my research yet, but my next step is to learn exactly how to create a WPF User Control Library manually (the code and various project property settings), and then I can just save a WPF User Control Library skeleton for future use and document the details.

UPDATE: This guy totally has the solution for Express versions. I have followed his steps and it works great. The only additional piece of information I would add is that in my version (VSE2013), after you've created your WPF User Control Library template, when you open Visual Studio again and use File -> New Project, my selection in the tree (for a Windows app) came up under Templates -> Visual C# -> Windows (which is what I've been using). I did not see my template showing up there, after I created it, and I thought, "Great! Another piece of advice that doesn't work." But then I clicked up one on the "Visual C#" parent - and there was the template!

Here you go:

How to add a WPF control library template to Visual C# Express 2008
https://dotupdate.wordpress.com/2007/12/05/how-to-add-a-wpf-control-library-template-to-visual-c-express-2008/

Yes, it works this way for VSE2013 too.

UPDATE 2: I'm not absolutely positive about this, but I think he missed one little piece. In his step #4 he says to delete Window1.xaml and App.xaml. Maybe this didn't apply with VSE 2008, but in VSE 2013 there is also the App.config file which I believe is extraneous for our purpose. So you can delete App.config as well. As I said, I'm not absolutely certain about this yet, but I noticed that file in the project when I added a WPF User Control Library project to my solution, and I deleted it, and the solution compiled okay.

Comment: Thank u very much @Steve Greene I was struggling with it for days. It helped me a lot. Thanks for the detailed guidance.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. The bad advice is so profuse because so many did not actually understand the issue in regard to the Express version - it was very confusing until I realized the real problem in regard to Express.

Answer (score 0):

Try running devenv with the /installvstemplates switch, from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms247116(v=vs.100).aspx

If this doesn't work, browse to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\CSharp\WPF\1033\WPFUserControl (this could change dependent upon your installation directory), open the .vstemplate file in a text editor, and make sure the  setting is set to true, then try running devenv with the switch again.

Hope it helps.